Como evitar que un nuevo registro tenga el mismo código que el ultimo registro con c# y sql
Por ejemplo se elimino el registro con Id "4", al agregar un nuevo registro automáticamente se registra con Id "6" pero es el mismo Id del ultimo registro guardado

Cuando le doy Guardar al nuevo registro, sale esta alerta:


El ID es autiincrement, seguirá subiendo. Ahora, por que eliminas un registro? si por algo debe estar o estuvo ahi, de ahi el nombre, registro.

Es raro que elimines categorias.. tu pregunta esta incompleta porque no sabemos que datos tiene ese query para tirar ese error... Pero si eliminas categorias, que pasa con los registros que linkeaban a esa categoria???

Tienen razón, no lo había visto de esa manera no debería de eliminar las categorías, sino que solo se pueden editar

La forma en la que calculas o estableces codigo antes de llamar a insertarcategoria es la clave para saber por qué. Pero no lo estas mostrando
